# Compiler for 32-bit LSB MIPS MIPS32 architecture

Tags: linux, c, c++, cross-compilation, compiler

I have a TV set top box that i'm currently experimenting on:

[image]

I established a serial console connection to it through a serial port located on the board. I am trying to compile a simple C executable to run on this device but I can't seem to find out how to do so.

I tried CodeSourcery, cross-compiler-mipsel and uClibc but they didn't work and in the later was very confusing to build with its configuration options.

Here is the data I was able to collect about the system:

#### A sample file architechture:

```
apps-startup: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.12, stripped
```

#### System information:

```
tangox[/]# uname -a
Linux tangox 2.6.22.19-40-sigma #3230 PREEMPT Thu Oct 3 15:54:23 IST 2013 mips GNU/Linux
```

#### cpuinfo:

```
tangox[/]# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
system type             : Sigma Designs TangoX
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 24K V7.12  FPU V0.0
Initial BogoMIPS                : 332.59
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes
ASEs implemented        : mips16
shadow register sets    : 1
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

SMP8XXX Chip ID         : 8653
SMP8XXX Rev ID          : 2
System bus frequency    : 333000000 Hz
CPU frequency           : 499500000 Hz
DSP frequency           : 333000000 Hz
```

#### dmesg:

```
tangox[/]# dmesg
Linux version 2.6.22.19-40-sigma (buildmgr@hulk) (gcc version 4.3.2 (Sourcery G++ Lite 4.3-51) ) #3230 PREEMPT Thu Oct 3 15:54:23 IST 2013
Mixed DRAM usage enabled.
Configured for SMP865x, detected SMP8653 (revision ES2).
Detected CPU/System/DSP Frequencies: 499.50/333.00/333.00MHz
SMP86xx Enabled Devices under Linux/XENV 0x9f3fbff4 = 0x003303f8
....
```

#### Files and directories:

```
tangox[/]# ls
apps@             images/           mrua_SMP8654F/    sysfs/
apps-peer/        init*             mruafw/           system@
bin/              initial_settings/ opt/              tmp/
cpgui/            lib/              probe/            upgrade/
data/             linuxrc@          proc/             usr/
dcchd_SMP8652/    logd/             rfs/              var/
dev/              lost+found/       root/             vnms/
etc/              media@            sbin/             webkit/
home/             mnt/              sys/

tangox[/]# find . -type f -name *.c
tangox[/]# find . -type f -name *.h
tangox[/]# find . -type f -name *.cpp
tangox[/]# find . -type f -name *.hpp
tangox[/]# find . -type f -name *.so
./webkit/lib/libcplibutils.so
./webkit/lib/libbrowserutils.so
./webkit/lib/plugins/npswitch.so
./webkit/lib/plugins/npplayer.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/directfb/lib/libdirectfb-smp86xx.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_dtv.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmcdda.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_acap.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmdvdfs.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmdvdfsapi.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_core.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmdvdvideoapi.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_tuner.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmvcdnavapi.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmpacketcommand.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmdisc.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_cap.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_mcast.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_dvd.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmdvdvideonav.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmcddanavapi.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_dvdvr.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/librmvcdnav.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd_lpb.so
./dcchd_SMP8652/dcchd/lib/libdcchd.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libndsp.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libruai2c.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmkvdemux.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libindex.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdtcpapi.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmp4core.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdrm.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libruahdmi.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmtextsubs.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libaudiooutports.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcore.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmasfdemuxcore.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmi2c.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmonitoring.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmpeg4framework.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmm_g.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libvp6decoder.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmhsi.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcpputils.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librua.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmpegsystemindex.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libdcc.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmwmaprodecodercore.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmflv.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmzlib.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmm_t.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcapture.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libgbus.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmriff.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libllad.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdetector3api.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libdisplayoutports.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcdfs_t.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmlibplay_t.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmstreamingprotocols.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdetectorapi.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmpegdemux.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcprminterface.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdetector3.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmhdmi.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libsh263decoder.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmwmdrmstub.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmp4api.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmwmaprodecoder.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcurl.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmedid.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdescriptordecoder.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmpthreadw.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmasfdemux.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmavicore.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmvdemux.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmsubidx.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmvideoout.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmrtk86.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcec.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmm.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmsoftmixer.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdvbsubs.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcpputils_t.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmsha1.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmppf.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmfp_t.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmchannel.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libruahsi.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmhttp.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcdfs.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmp4.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/libsamples_t.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmfontrender.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmdisplay.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmscc.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcw.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmmpegsystemindexcreator.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmcssinterface.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmwmdrmndstub.so
./mrua_SMP8654F/lib/librmsofttxt.so
./data/myapps/tvstreamer/lib/libmpr.so
./data/myapps/tvstreamer/lib/libpcre.so
./data/myapps/tvstreamer/lib/libvuxmlgen.so
./data/myapps/tvstreamer/lib/libappweb.so
./data/myapps/tvstreamer/lib/modules/mod_vuxml.so
./lib/libnss_compat-2.8.so
./lib/libthread_db-1.0.so
./lib/libtinyxml.so
./lib/libIStagecraft.so
./lib/libnss_nis-2.8.so
./lib/ld-2.8.so
./lib/libIURLOps.so
./lib/libnss_files-2.8.so
./lib/libpcprofile.so
./lib/libIStreamPlayer.so
./lib/libIFL31NativeSoundOutput.so
./lib/libIXMLReaderLib.so
./lib/libSegFault.so
./lib/libresolv-2.8.so
./lib/libIEDKExtensions.so
./lib/libm-2.8.so
./lib/libarchop_74k.so
./lib/libIAEKernel.so
./lib/libsqlite.so
./lib/libutil-2.8.so
./lib/libtomcrypt.so
./lib/libIShell.so
./lib/libIVideoDecoder.so
./lib/libnss_nisplus-2.8.so
./lib/libIFileSystem.so
./lib/libIAudioDecoder.so
./lib/libcrypt-2.8.so
./lib/libIImageDecoder.so
./lib/libnss_hesiod-2.8.so
./lib/libISocket.so
./lib/libIStream.so
./lib/libBrokenLocale-2.8.so
./lib/libIFlashLib.so
./lib/libIIO.so
./lib/librt-2.8.so
./lib/libViewRightWebClient.so
./lib/libanl-2.8.so
./lib/libnss_dns-2.8.so
./lib/libIGraphicsDriver.so
./lib/libIJSONParserLib.so
./lib/libarchop_24k.so
./lib/libIProcess.so
./lib/libnsl-2.8.so
./lib/libc-2.8.so
./lib/libcidn-2.8.so
./lib/libpthread-2.8.so
./lib/libmemusage.so
./lib/libdl-2.8.so
```

There are no kernel or library headers but only static libraries. How do I create binaries that are compatible with this board?

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/historic-linux/early-ports/Mips/www/build.html and https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains should get you started. I only built a netbsd ARM toolchain in x86 lately.

Answer (score 1):

Of course nobody will leave any source code on embedded system, because this is unnecessary. Embedded systems like yours usually have little space even to store their firmware.

You see that it contains glibc. It's seen by presence of shared objects in `/lib` version-named `-2.8.so`. You need glibc compatible toolchain which contains glibc 2.8 or *earlier* to compile binaries for this system.

Or you can abandon idea of building with glibc and just statically link your executables with uClibc toolchain. Use `-static` command line argument.

Building with musl libc is even easier and there are already toolchains for that. You just put one `libc.so` into `/lib`, dynamic linker symlink to it and your binary somewhere.

I hope `apps-startup` is from your board and you already know what endianness it runs.

And you did not mentioned your requirements for your simple C executable. Maybe it requires additional libraries that you probably will need to build.

Comment: I'm new to cross compiling and have average knowledge in gcc so i'm not sure how to use `glibc`, `uclibc` or `musl libc` yet. However i tried `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` with these flags `-EL -mips32` and was able to compile a simple program that loops 10 times and print something each time. What i'm trying to do now is to compile `openssh-server` for this board but i'm getting problems with `zlib` library, could you direct me to some sources where i can learn how to do that i would appreciate it. The `apps-start` is from the board btw.

Comment: I did not tried cross compiling `openssh` for other architectures, and you'll not only need `zlib` but also `openssl`, which is tricky to compile (not even saying to cross compile). I can suggest you building `dropbear` instead - it has all crypto code inside and today it's nearly same grade ssh server as `openssh`.

Comment: And if you want to cross compile stuff with packages that use `configure`, you need to pass something like `--host=mips-linux-gnu` when compiling. And if you need additional dependencies, you need to point to them with additional `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` like that: `./configure --host=mips-linux-gnu --prefix= CFLAGS=-I/path/to/libs/include LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/libs/lib`, where `/path/to/libs` is where you're going to install libraries dependencies for mips architecture (install somewhere in your `/home`).

Comment: And if you're really need `openssh`, I suggest you not messing with `openssl` but use `libressl` fork instead - it has at least very nice cleaned up build system which do not tie you to know crippled internals and having perl as build time requirement.